# ASP.NET C# - Showing right contentplaceholder in default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to help friend with his website which is written in asp.net. I am newbie in asp.net but I know php and mysql. Right know I am trying to figure out, how to declare which page (something.aspx) is shown in ContentPlaceHolder.

For example:

I have one master page (web.master) on which I have:

> < asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cpMainContent" runat="server">

Then I have many content pages (f.e. article.aspx, section.apsx) on which I have:

> < asp:Content ID="Something" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent" runat="server">Some content

So my question is, how the website knows which .aspx file to open? If I open my friends website, I found out, that in cpMainContent is content from file section.aspx. If I make new page, like section2.aspx, how should I let the website know, that it should use the new created page?

Thank you very much for responses.

Comment: Content Pages are the pages user can access not master pages directly... 
So.... add a link to the page you want to direct to, its simple....

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

the msdn article pretty explains almost everything, I suggest you read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new page, you give it a name and before you press "ADD" you can check off to "Select Master Page". It will bring up a dialog box of all master pages in the project and you can select one. Easy as that!

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that I am working on website that I didn't created. And in this project, there is only one master page - web.master. I need to define, that when user is on default.aspx it will display in ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpMainContent" content from section_home.aspx (right now it displays content from section.aspx and I need to change it)

Comment: @midz, that's sounds a bit strange... Are you sure you're talking about an aspx file here, and not about a usercontrol (.ASCX)? With webforms, the displayed content for default.aspx should either be in default.aspx or in separate usercontrols....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but if the page is already created, the master page that it gets connected to is defined in the page directive like this MasterPageFile="~/Master.master". You can change the name of the file over there

Comment: yes I know that, but I have only one masterpagefile for whole website. When I compile my website, it takes me to localhost:50165/default.aspx. From what I understand, this site consists of web.master (which is masterpage for whole project) and section.aspx which is in contentplaceholder cpMainContent. And I need web.master to show content from section_home.aspx instead of section.aspx.

Comment: The assumption that section.aspx is in contentplaceHolder is incorrect. An ASPX page contains Content controls that map to a corresponding ContentPlaceHolder in the master page. You navigatie to default.aspx, you see content from default.aspx as defined in its 'Content' controls. When you navigate to section.aspx, you see content from the controls in that section.aspx

Comment: when you compile your website you are not running the master but rather the child page that gets some layout based on the master. You have Default.aspx set to your startup page, that's what will load. You want to load the Section_Home.aspx as startup which is based on your master page.

Comment: Ok I got it wrong, but another problem is, when I open default.aspx.cs, there is some redirection to /cz/Default.aspx and I don't know where to find this default.aspx in my project (cz is language code).

Comment: Can you just set Section_Home.aspx to be your home page? It seems like you don't care for Deafult.aspx eitherway. Otherwise you can just do a grand search on your whole project for it. It has to be there somewhere if your site uses it,

Comment: And how do I set it as my homepage? I thought that homepage has to be named Default.aspx. Thank you!

Comment: no. In your solution, you can right click on the page that you would like to set and click "Set As Start Page".

Comment: You might have to add this your web.config as well so it will work after you publish the site.  <defaultDocument enabled="true"> <files><add value="Home.aspx" /></files></defaultDocument>

Comment: I tried to search within solution explorer to find default.aspx and only one i found was the one that i mentioned above (the one with the redirection). Also when i right clicked on section_home.apsx there is no such option to set as start page

Comment: Oh - I forgot to ask if you're using Visual Studio. I fyou are, you have to stop debugging and then right click on page. It should be there if you're not debugging,.

Comment: Also, don't search your solution explorer, search in your project for those words because the page usually has it's name on it.

Comment: And is there a way how to find current start page? I still don't understand what page is opening when I compile my project. In address bar, there is localhost:50165/default.aspx but when I open default.aspx in my project, there is totally different content.

Comment: You could check in your web.config for defaultDocument

Answer (score 0):

Master pages are not accessed directly by the user. Redirection can be performed by adding the directory pathto the anchor tag to other pages( content pages associated with master pages/ not associated with master page ).